# Batch File to start chrome:chrome and update

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file to force Google Chrome to Update. If I use the following it is close however the batch file below takes out the `:` and shows a `This Site Can't Be Reached` notification:

```
@echo on
start chrome.exe \chrome://chrome
pause
```

If I had a batch file to open chrome:chrome in a startup page that would be helpful as well.

Comment: What about `start "" chrome.exe "\chrome://chrome"` or `start "" chrome.exe "\\chrome\://chrome"`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the profile manager and create a user/profile with chrome://chrome as the start page. Or manually/per batch create a copy of the preferences file in `"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"` and switch between two versions of the file. 
The following batch will just create a backup with datetime appended to the name to start with.

```
@Echo off
:: GetISODT
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=.+-" %%A in (
  'wmic os get LocalDateTime^|findstr ^^[0-9]'
    ) do Set _DT=%%A

Pushd "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"
copy Preferences Preferences_%_DT%
start chrome
```